# How do I set all objects in my scene to be aligned with respect to the camera in Unity 3D?

Tags: cameras, 3d-reconstruction

To elaborate further - How do I fix the camera as the origin of the 3D world?

The context is I am trying to create some synthetic image data for a robotics project, and I have the coordinates of the End Effector in the camera frame (basically the position of the object and its orientation in the camera coordinates) How do I set the Unity setup such that if I set the X, Y, Z and rotation of the object in camera coordinates, it recreates the scene?

[Unity 3D]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a robotic arm in Unity?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/18981/how-to-render-a-robotic-arm-in-unity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is [`TransformPoint(Vector3 position)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html). You can describe something in coordinates that are *local* to the camera and use the `TransformPoint()` method to convert from local camera coordinates to world coordinates.

It sounds like you're trying to make a scene to generate some test data, in which case you'll have to have a list of objects you want to arrange and a list of positions and rotations that are local to the camera. You can try maintaining these as separate objects, but you should consider making the "local objects" into a class of its own. You can use a `[System.Serializable]` tag before the class definition to have the class be able to populate in the editor.

So, for example, you might have:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LocalObject
{
    public GameObject localObject;
    public Vector3 localPosition;
    public void UpdateTransform()
    {
        if(localObject!=null)
        {
            localObject.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.TransformPoint(localPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

So with that code you have a `LocalObject` that consists of a `GameObject` and a `Vector3` that describes the transform in local coordinates, and then finally a method that will set the position by transforming the location from main camera coordinates to world coordinates via the `TransformPoint()` command.

Since it's using the `[System.Serializable]` tag, it can be exposed in the editor, such that you can have something like:

```
public class YourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<LocalObject> localObjects = new List<LocalObject>();
```

Then later, in `Start()` or `Update()`, you can iterate through your list and set the positions:

```
void Start()
{
    foreach(LocalObject localObject in localObjects)
    { 
        localObject.UpdateTransform();
    }
}
```

The rotations relative to the camera is a going to be a little trickier because Unity represents the rotations as quaternions, but I think the approach I would take would be to use the `forward`, `right`, and `up` properties of the `Transform` as an input for the [`Quaternion.AngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) command, then build a series of quaternions using that command and setting the rotation that way. For example, by modifying the `LocalObject` class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LocalObject
{
    public GameObject localObject;
    public Vector3 localPosition;
    public Vector3 localRotation; // new
    private Transform cam = Camera.main.transform; // new, just to make referencing easier
    public void UpdateTransform()
    {
        if(localObject!=null)
        {
            localObject.transform.position = cam.TransformPoint(localPosition);
            Quaternion roll = Quaternion.AngleAxis(localRotation.x, cam.forward); // new
            Quaternion pitch = Quaternion.AngleAxis(localRotation.y, cam.right); // new
            Quaternion yaw = Quaternion.AngleAxis(localRotation.z, cam.up); // new
            localObject.transform.rotation = yaw*pitch*roll; // new
        }
    }
}
```

I *think* that would do it, but I'm just typing this into the text box here and haven't tried any of this in Unity. Also Unity uses left-handed coordinates with y-axis as up, but I think most people would be most familiar as entering the angles as roll-pitch-yaw and would like yaw to be about the vertical axis, which again is y in Unity, so there might be some sign errors or something in the above, but this should give you a good idea of how to do what you want.